# Modifying scripts of branching

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to do away with branching operators, but I don't know how I could optimize my script, I'm wondering, Promise to use? But inside it I'll write branching operators again, I'm very interested to hear your point of view on how I could do it, I couldn't find examples of my question, but I'm very interested in how I could optimize it more. I'm a newbie, don't judge me too harshly.

Again, I tried to create a Promise but I know that again I will put branching operators in it.

I would be grateful for any advice.

```
const User = await User.findByPk(ctx.match[1]);

await User.update({
  Value_U: ctx.match[2] == 'accepted' ? 1 : 2,
});

if (User.Value_U == 1) {
  ctx.reply('Success')
}

if (User.Value_U == 2) {
  ctx.reply('Reject')
}

if (User.Value_U == 3) {
  ctx.reply('OK')
}

const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

})
```

Comment: No need for any extra promise here.

Comment: How about `ctx.reply({ 1: 'Success', 2: 'Reject', 3: 'OK' }[User.Value_U] ?? 'Unknown')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array or object containing functions, and index them using `User.Value_U`.

```
let actions = {
    1: () => ctx.reply('Success'),
    2: () => ctx.reply('Reject'),
    3: () => ctx.reply('OK')
};

action[User.Value_U]();
```